# Cartesian product of "infinite empty sets"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Cartesian product $\emptyset\times\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$, since $A\times B=\emptyset \iff A=\emptyset \text{ or} B=\emptyset$. Can one therefore conclude that $\emptyset^\infty=\emptyset$, or is it undefined the same way as $0^\infty$ on the extended reals? (Or is there another answer?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, it is my opinion that in set theory one should *never* use the notation $A^\infty$, and that instead an indexing set for the product should always be specified: for instance $A^{\Bbb N}$, $A^{\Bbb R}$, $A^{\aleph_3}$. This falls naturally with the actual definition of $A^B$ as the set of functions having domain $B$ and codomain $A$, not to mention that it saves hand-waving and need of superfluous ingenuity. With that in mind, it is no mystery what $\emptyset^A$ is: being the set of functions with domain $A$ and codomain $\emptyset$, it's $\{\emptyset\}$ if $A=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ if $A\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: "it is my opinion" It is more than your opinion, it is **true**! :P

Comment: To the OP re: the last sentence, note that since functions are (in set theory) sets of ordered pairs, $\emptyset$ is a function as well as a set: it's the empty function, which does nothing to nothing. So "$\emptyset^\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}$" means "There is exactly one function from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$, namely the empty function - which is itself $\emptyset$, because of how we're representing functions in set theory."

Comment: Thank your for both the answer and the additional information! Both are really helpful and to the point!